# Erro ao fazer busca GET com queries

Tags: node.js, get

Olá, criei em minha aplicação uma roda /search do tipo GET, porem quando tento enviar uma requisição com queries pelo aplicativo insomnia, o terminal do nodejs retorna dois erros, o primeiro é:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined

Ao analisar esse erro achei que o problema estava em uma função que criei para trabalhar com arrays e string, segue a função:

```
function parseStringAsArray(arrayAsString) {
    return arrayAsString.split(',').map(tech => tech.trim())
}
```

Já o segundo erro acontece ao tentar exportar essa função, segue o erro:

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This
>   error originated either by throwing inside of an async function
>   without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled
>   with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise
>   rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see
>   https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode).
>   (rejection id: 1) (node:1804) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled
>   promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections
>   that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a
>   non-zero exit code.

Imagem da query:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Codigo da rota /search:

```
const Dev = require('../models/Dev')
const parseStringAsArray = require('../utils/parseStringAsArray')

module.exports

 = {
    async index(request, response) {
        const {
            latitude,
            longitude,
            techs
        } = request.body

        const techsArray = parseStringAsArray(techs)

        const devs = await Dev.find({
            techs: {
                $in: techsArray,
            },
            location: {
                $near: {
                    $geometry: {
                        type: 'Point',
                        coordinates: [longitude, latitude],
                    },
                    $maxDistance: 10000,
                }
            },
        })

        return response.json({
            devs: []
        })
    }
}
```

***OBS: Sou iniciante em NodeJS então obrigado por quem tentar me ajudar!***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pelo conteúdo do seu post, me parece que este código é da semana OmniStack 10 da Rocketseat.

O erro do split ocorre porque ele está esperando receber uma string, desta forma, ele vai quebrar a string em um array, utilizando a vírgula como separador, por exemplo, a string "React,PHP" criaria um array com dois itens ["React", "PHP"]

Seria interessante postar o código da sua rota "Search", aqui segue um exemplo que deve te ajudar a entender melhor o problema

```
const Dev                   = require('../models/Dev');
const parseStringAsArray    = require('../utils/ParseStringAsArray');

module.exports = {
    async index (req, resp) {
        // Search devs for techs and distance

        const { lat, long, techs } = req.query;

        const arrayTechs = parseStringAsArray(techs);

        //Programação da rota

    }
};
```

Perceba neste exemplo que "lat", "long" e "techs" são os parâmetros da URL que você enviou ao chamar a rota search. Se não existir o "techs" como parâmetro, vai ocorrer o erro.

O outro erro pode ser por causa que você criou uma função async mas não usou o "await", aqui tem um código de exemplo:

```
const Dev                   = require('../models/Dev');
const parseStringAsArray    = require('../utils/ParseStringAsArray');

module.exports = {
    async index (req, resp) {
        // Search devs for techs and distance

        const { lat, long, techs } = req.query;

        const arrayTechs = parseStringAsArray(techs);

         const devs = await Dev.find({
             techs: {
                 $in: arrayTechs,    
             },
             locations: {
                 $near: { // Parametro do mongo para localidade próxima
                     $geometry: { // Objeto que recebe latitude e longitude
                         type: 'Point', // tipo
                         coordinates: [long, lat], // array de numbers
                     },
                     $maxDistance: 10000, // Parametro do mongo para a distância máxima
                 },
             },
        });

        return resp.json({ devs });
    }
};
```

Comment: Ola, obrigado pela resposta, porem eu tentei fazer algumas alterações, e quando eu faço o request pelo insomnia, eu recebo apenas esse resultado:                                                                                                                               
{
  "devs": []
}, e não a collection com os dados do usuario que possuem as mesmas tecnologias que eu coloquei, oque sera que pode ser? alem disso eu postei minha /search na publicação!

Comment: Você precisa alterar esta linha : return response.json({devs: []}), você está enviado por padrão sempre um array vazio.  Como você já está fazendo a pesquisa e guardando numa variável dev, altere a linha para response.json({devs}),

Comment: Então, usando o request.params eu consegui obter os resultados, porem pra funcionar pro mobile seria com o request.body certo? quando uso o .body ele retorna os mesmos erros de antes, o que sera que pode ser?

Comment: Edit: eu consegui resolver o erro, muito obrigado Bins, me ajudou demais!!